# How to fit HTML table row to its content

Tags: html, css

My `<table>` has three rows and columns, with the last table row like this:

```
<tr>
 <td colspan="3" align="center" valign="top" style="background-color: #eeeeee;">
  <hr class="vdivider">
  <div class="sitemap">There's an unordered list in here</div>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Now the odd thing that I can not figure out is that the `<tr>` is almost twice as high as its content.  Both `<hr>` and `<div>` together sit quite nicely aligned to the top of the table row, and then there are almost 150px empty space to the bottom of the table.  Padding and margin and border for all elements are 0, and there is not much other styling to the table or its rows/columns other than this:

```
html, body, table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

How can I make that table row fit the height of its content, and get rid of the big space at the bottom?  I have assigned the height to the table here to make sure it stretches to the bottom of the window if the window is larger than the table would be.  I assume that is where the overly large `<tr>` originates.  To compensate for that stretch, I tried to add the extra `<tr>` above the sitemap with a `min-height:100px; max-height:none;` but that didn't help.

**EDIT** Fixed typos.

**EDIT** Maybe a little more background on this.

```
+--------------------------------+  browser window (html body)
| +----------------------------+ |
| |       banner image         | |  there is a banner image here that stretches across the page
| +----------------------------+ |
| | css menu bar               | |  a standard CSS menu built from ul
| +----------------------------+ |  this is where the table starts, it has three columns
| |  td   |  td           | td | |
| |       |               |    | |
| +----------------------------+ |
| | tr colspan=3 to make space | |  there's column to make space between content above and sitemap below
| +----------------------------+ |
| | tr colspan=3 for sitemap   | |  tr from above, the sitemap which stretches way down if table { height: 100%; }
| +----------------------------+ |
|                                |  this is the space in large windows when table has no height setting.
+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: Have u reset the UL tag also? use padding and margin 0px

Comment: `There's a &lt;ul&gt; here` **not** `There's a <ul> here`.

Comment: @SudipPal: Yes.  @Mr_Green: What I meant to say is that inside of the `<div>` there is an unordered list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thank you for the feedback!  Removing the `table { height: 100%; }` did not work because it doesn't stretch the table to the bottom of the page.  This stretching is what I wanted, but I think this is also what caused the overly inflated `<tr>` which this question refers to.

The solution to this was more of an accident:

```
<tr style="height: 0;">
  ...
</tr>
```

With this, the row shrinks to the size of its content, while the table still stretches to the bottom of the page.  Not sure if this is a "healthy" solution, but is sure works.

Comment: Recently I had the same problem, but I couldn't get it to work until I set the height to 1px.

Comment: Actually (tested on Chrome 51.0.2704.103) for me at least one row had to have ```height: 1``` in order to work. I added an empty line to my tab with height to 1 and it worked.

Comment: 0 seems to work in Chrome, but not FF. 1px or 1% seems to work in both browsers.

Answer (score 2):

remove height

```
html, body, table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

and it looks like this (no more overhead in `<tr>` `height`)

[image]

Why 100% height on `html` and `body` anyway? Also, I would change `There's a <ul> here` to `There's a &lt;ul> here`

Comment: Removing the height:100% did the trick, so it seems. I think setting this is a relic from old code I have never really revisited—it's not necessary?  Actually, no, it didn't.  When I remove the `height` then the last table row isn't sitting at the bottom of the browser window the window is larger than the table.  It seems I could need another "rubber `<tr>`" that allows to stretch...

Answer (score 0):

Once that you fix your tags and close them properly you will see that the `TR` height is that big because `UL` margins are stretching it, if you modify the CSS for this tag it will be smaller [check it here](http://jsfiddle.net/dGWbt/4/)

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

For other side like your table has only 1 row, if you add the style `height: 100%` to the table, that row will stretch to the maximum, you can modify the style to leave it like this [check it](http://jsfiddle.net/dGWbt/3/)

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Removing the `height:100%` does solve the problem of the tr fitting to its content, but then the end of the table does not align and stretch to the bottom of the body anymore...

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/9jMR8/
Maybe like this? Changed the bg-color of the div..

Changed the css like this:

```
html, body{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
table{
border:1px solid black;     
width:100%;
}
div{
background-color:blue;
}
```