# Fit the Cell content to the cell height in HTML CSS table

Tags: css, html

I have a css styled table generated using following code. I tried to fit the cell height with the content (here its DATA1 and DATA2). But I am unable to generate a **cell with content fit to the height**. How can I do that?

I tried with something mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342181/how-to-fit-html-table-row-to-its-content), but It doesnt showed ant change. Please note that I have kept width as 100% and I focus only on height fit.

```
<style>
#customers 
{
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
width: 100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
}


#customers td, #customers th 
{    
border: 1px solid #98bf21;
padding: 3px 7px 2px 7px;
font-size:15px
}


#customers tr.alt td
{
color: #000000;
background-color: #EAF2D3;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table id="customers"> 
<tr class="alt">
<td>DATA1 </td>
<td>DATA2</td>    
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: your problem is that the cell is 2-3 pixels bigger from top and bottom of content? (data1 and 2 )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <style>
#customers 
{
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

border-collapse: collapse;
}


#customers td, #customers th 
{    
border: 1px solid #98bf21;
line-height:10px;
font-size:15px
}


#customers tr.alt td
{
color: #000000;
background-color: #EAF2D3;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table id="customers"> 
<tr class="alt">
<td>DATA1 </td>
<td>DATA2</td>    
</tr>
</table>
```

remove padding from #customer td and #th and it would sort down the gap from top and bottom between cell and content and use line-height:Xpx to make cell touching the content (or even go over your content)

Comment: But removing padding also leave some space in between the tip of content and the border line. Actually, I wanted the content to touch the top and bottom border lines @iMMuNiTy

Comment: add line-height: 10px in ur example to accomplish that